# System.out.printlns error which prints multiple times instead of once? (Java - New info)

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, this is a loop in which the if input.equals stuff is fine but for the last else if (the bomb one) it for some reason prints out either 2 or 3 or one of that Ouch you got hit, at the same time subtracting 3*how many times it was printed. Why is it doing this and how can I fix it? I think when the tries are subtracted, is it possible it restarts the while loop? Bombs[][] is a two-dim array which stores true and false values to define wether or not there is a bomb there. I am fairly sure the problem is with the setup of the if-else statement though :/ I just figured out that when I add the input.equals(pos[][]) to the last else-if statement, it breaks the printing out of the Ouch message so nothing is printed. When I put in all of the other variables it works but not that one.

```
boolean[][]bombs = new boolean[10][10];
    while(bombs2>=0)
    {
    for(int a=0; a<=9;a++)
    {
        for(int b=0;b<=9;b++)
        {
            if(bombs2>=0)
            {
            random2 = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            if((random2 == 48) && tof[a][b] == false)
            {
            bombs[a][b] = true;
            bombs2--;
            }

            else
            {
                bombs[a][b] = false;
            }
           }
        }
    }
    }

int tries = 13;
  while(playing==true && tries>0)
    {
    Scanner next = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.println("Coordinate: ");
    System.out.println("testing");
    String input = next.nextLine();
    for(int m = 0; m<=9;m++)
    {
        for(int n = 0; n<=9;n++)///Output after each coordinate is guessed.
        {
            if ((input.equals(pos[m][n])) && tof[m][n] == true && m == vertcol && n == horcol && bombs[m][n] == false)
            {
                System.out.println("Congratulations! You won the game and found the coordinate!");
                playing = false;
            }
            else if ((input.equals(pos[m][n])) && tof[m][n] == false && m == vertcol && n!= horcol && bombs[m][n] == false)
            {
                System.out.println("Miss, but the square you are looking for is somewhere in this vertical column.");
                tries--;
            }
            else if ((input.equals(pos[m][n])) && tof[m][n] == false && n == horcol && m!= vertcol&& bombs[m][n] == false)
            {
                System.out.println("Miss, but the square you are looking for is somewhere in this horizontal column.");
                tries--;
            }
            else if((input.equals(pos[m][n])) && tof[m][n] == false && n!= horcol && m!= vertcol&& bombs[m][n] == false)
            {
                System.out.println("Complete Miss.");
                tries--;
            }
            **else if(bombs[m][n] == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Ouch! You got hit by a bomb! Minus three tries.");
                tries -= 3;**
            }
        }
    }
}
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Debug your code. Either use a debugger such as you can find in NetBeans or Eclipse, or sprinkle your code with println statements to check on the values of a, b, bombs2, your random variable...

Comment: Please have a little patience. You've only asked this question 3 hours ago and are already posting non-sense bumps to the answer. First thing to consider is to delete those distracting comments and improving your question by explaining more of the details of your problem including your overall goals and other important background information.

Comment: Sorry. I deleted all the stuff. Also, if I seem nervous it is because this project thing is due tomorrow.....so it has to be done in 12 hours :/

Comment: Let me get this right -- you want to randomly assign 10 trues (bombs) into a 10 x0 10 2-D array of booleans that have been initialized to false, something similar to minesweeper?

Comment: Exactly. There is also one coordinate that you need to find but that part of the code is not bugged. Just this last printing part.

Answer (score 3):

```
random2 = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        if(random2 == 49 && bombs2>0 && tof[a][b] == false && bombs[a][b] == false)
```

There's no guarantee here that random2 will *ever* be equal to 49.  Thus, you are not seeing any bombs.

In addition, I'm not sure why some of your variables have a 2 at the end.  If you need to number your variables, it's usually an indication that they're not being named well.  For example, as far as I can tell, your 2-dimensional array is not really an array of bombs, but rather it represents a bomb field(?).

Comment: I'd recommend generating a few random pairs of coordinates (maybe store that in a `LinkedList<Dimension>`?). Then each time through the loop, it can see if that location is on the list.

Comment: That way, it would only have to run through the loop once, not an unknown amount of times

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to place 10 bombs randomly into a 10x10 grid (10 trues into a 10 by 10 array of falses), then this is essentially the same as placing 10 items randomly into 100 slots. A simple way to do this is to use a List, shuffle the List and then interact with the shuffled list. Note that java.util.Lists must use reference types and not primitive types, and so if they were filled with booleans, you would have to use Booleans instead. If you want to stick with your boolean array, then you could use a `List<Integer>` shuffle it, and then remove the first ten shuffled Integers in the list and assign your bombs this way. For instance:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BombArray {
   private static final int SIDE = 10;
   private static final int BOMB_COUNT = 10;
   // default filled with 0
   private static boolean[][] bombs = new boolean[SIDE][SIDE];

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // create our List if Integer
      List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
      // fill it with monotonically increasing ints
      for (int i = 0; i < SIDE* SIDE; i++) {
         intList.add(i);
      }
      // shuffle the collection
      Collections.shuffle(intList);
      // take the first 10 items and use the value to place bombs
      // into our array
      for (int i = 0; i < BOMB_COUNT; i++) {
         int randomValue = intList.remove(0);
         int row = randomValue / SIDE;
         int col = randomValue % SIDE;
         bombs[row][col] = true;
      }

      // test the code out
      System.out.println("Lets test the array:\n");
      for (int row = 0; row < bombs.length; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < bombs[row].length; col++) {
            boolean bomb = bombs[row][col];
            String text = bomb ? " *T* " : "  F  ";
            System.out.print(text);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Hover, you don't seem to understand. The randomizer works perfectly. The part that doesn't seem to work is the printing out when it is a bomb. It never prints out just 1 "Ouch....". The randomizer itself works fine.

Comment: @Lifezdioj: where's the code where you test your randomizer to be sure? For example, note the block of code in my code above that begins with `// test the code out`

Comment: Let this be a lesson to you to not leave your project until the last day and expect Stack Overflow to provide you with a solution.  In addition, Hovercraft asked how you know that the randomizer is "working perfectly", yet you ignore that completely and post nonsensical bumps.